# How can i fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am studying a small project where I intend to render all API content in a single component and display it in steps, such as:

Page 1: Select engine

Page 2: Select color

Page 3: Select wheels

But I can't map the arrays of this API.

**App Component:**

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            correntEngine: null,
            correntColor: null,
            correntWheel: null,
            engine: [],
            color: [],
            wheels: [],
            finalPrice: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchBuildCar();
    }

    fetchBuildCar = async () => {
        const response = await api.get();
        const buildCar = response.data.data;
        this.setState({
            engine: buildCar.engine, 
            color: buildCar.color, 
            wheels: buildCar.wheels
        })
    }


    render() {
        const buildCar = this.state;
        return (
            <Router>
                <Container>
                    <div className="row content-home">
                        <Col lg={6}>Image</Col>
                        <Col lg={6}>
                            {buildCar.engine.items.map(item => (
                                        <h1>{item.type}</h1>
                                    ))}
                        </Col>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default ContentApp;
```

**API:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "price": 63000,
        "engine": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "P",
                    "kwh": 75,
                    "range": 275,
                    "price": 0,
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "type": "S",
                    "kwh": 100,
                    "range": 355,
                    "price": 5500,
                    "id": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "B",
                    "kwh": 125,
                    "range": 420,
                    "price": 10000,
                    "id": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        "color": {
            "description": "The 2009 Model R have 3 unique metalic color options. Each color was meticulously developed to look like something completely new to your eyes.",
            "items": [
                {
                    "hexadecimal": "#AB1725",
                    "label": "Metalic Vermilion",
                    "price": 0,
                    "id": 4
                },
                {
                    "hexadecimal": "#0F1C2D",
                    "label": "Thunderbolt Blue",
                    "price": 1200,
                    "id": 5
                },
                {
                    "hexadecimal": "#A8A8A8",
                    "label": "Space Grey",
                    "price": 1200,
                    "id": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        "wheels": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "label": "20” Silver Metalic",
                    "price": 0,
                    "id": 7
                },
                {
                    "label": "20” Grafitti",
                    "price": 2000,
                    "id": 8
                },
                {
                    "label": "22” Performance Carbon",
                    "price": 2000,
                    "id": 9
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I map the "items" return Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. How can I solve this?

Comment: at the first render, your `engine` is `[]`. It doesn't have `items` property.

Comment: but I can print buildCar.price or buildCar.color.description in my component

Comment: where do you print them? I can't see it on your question's code

Comment: The easiest way to fix this issue is modifying state in the constructor.
Like this, const buildCar = { engine: { items: [] }};

Comment: Hey, @FelipeNoka, did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code and it works well. Check the pictures below.

[image: Code Snippet]
[image]

Actually, your issue is not related to `map`.

The main issue is that render() function runs before the fetchApi return.

So write code like this.

`{buildCar.engine && buildCar.engine.items && buildCar.engine.items.map(item => ...`

Comment: You don't need to wrap `ul` with `Fragment`

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that others can actually copy and use your proposed solution without having to re-type everything, and your answer can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

`buildCar` does not exist in the render scope, you have to use state instead.

```
{this.state.engine.items.map(item => (
    <h1>{item.type}</h1>
))}
```

Comment: After rendering I created a constant buildCar getting this.state

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if data actually present when working with `componentDidMount`, because component first renders with your default state. You should do this,

```
{buildCar.engine.items && buildCar.engine.items.map(item => (
    <h1 key={item.id}>{item.type}</h1>
))}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-up5rqf)